# Generate random number of queues

Tags: c++, random, queue

Just out of curiosity, how does someone create a random number of queues?

I have a constructor like so from my current project:

```
public:

Passenger<NODETYPE> *super_express;
Passenger<NODETYPE> *express_line1;
Passenger<NODETYPE> *express_line2;
Passenger<NODETYPE> *regular_line;

Checkout_Simulation() : super_express("Super Express Counter 01"),
                            express_line1("Express Line Counter 01"),
                            express_line2("Express Line Counter 02"),
                            regular_line("Regular Line Counter 01"),
                            clock_time(0), finish_time(0) {}
```

How do you use a random generated number to create a random number of the regular_line queues? In other words, the random generator comes out as 5 which will make 5 regular_lines?

This is where they are run:

```
template <typename NODETYPE>
void Checkout_Simulation<NODETYPE> :: run_sim() {

    for(clock_time = 0; clock_time <total_time; clock_time++){
            item_obj.item_purchase(number);

    if (number < 15) {
      super_express.check_new_arrival(clock_time, display_all);
    // number = the value
      super_express.number = number;
    }
    else if (number >15 && number <=20){

      express_line1.check_new_arrival(clock_time, display_all);
      express_line2.check_new_arrival(clock_time, display_all);
    }
    else {
      regular_line.check_new_arrival(clock_time, display_all);
    }



    if (clock_time >= finish_time){
            start_checkout();
      }

    }//end for loop
}
```

Comment: Are the queues of the same type?

Comment: They are same time, only the number of items determines which customers goes in which one. (I haven't figured out just yet how to move the items inside the queues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a std::vector that has a random quantity of `Passenger<NODETYPE>` do the following:

First, you would generate a random number.
Next, use a loop to the limit of the random number.

```
srand(time(0); // Seed the random number generator.
const unsigned int quantity = rand() % 16 + 1;  
std::vector<Passenger<NODETYPE> *> regular_line_queues;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
{
  regular_line_queues.push_back(new Passenger<NODETYPE>);
}
```

Using a unique pointer or smart pointer is left as an exercise for the reader.

**Edit 1:**
For actual queues, replace `std::vector` with `std::deque`.

Comment: while using this formatting do I also need to change what the Constructor shows for the regular lines as well?